# Substring in a list of entries

Tags: batch-file

I have a variable that contains a list of filenames and based on the extension, I need to perform different action.
I am not able to extract the extension inside the loop

```
set BINARIES=file1.dll fil2.dll fil3.sys

:: for each file in list of binaries do
FOR %%G IN (%BINARIES%) DO (
    :: if extension is dll
    if /i [%%G:~-4%]==[.dll] (
        echo dll file
        ) else (
            echo sys file
        )
)
```

If condition is always failing. How to correctly extract the extension.

Answer (score 2):

```
if /i "%%~xG"==".dll"
```

From the cmd shell window help `for /?`:

```
In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
You can now use the following optional syntax:

    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
    %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
    %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
    %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
    %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
    %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
    %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
    %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
    %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
    %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable and expands %I to the
                   fully qualified name of the first one found.
                   If the environment variable name is not
                   defined or the file is not found by the
                   search, then this modifier expands to the
                   empty string

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

    %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
    %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
    %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
    %~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable for %I and expands to the
                   drive letter and path of the first one found.
    %~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can use this: %%G:~-4%

Also, you have to use delayed expansion of variables.
The key is using '!' instead of '%' in some places.
Check with "set /?", it gives a (confusing) example.

I don't remember very much the theory behind it, but this worked for me:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set BINARIES=file1.dll fil2.dll fil3.sys

:: for each file in list of binaries do
FOR %%G IN (%BINARIES%) DO (
    :: if extension is dll
    set x=%%g
    set y=!x:~-4!
    if /i [%y%]==[.dll] (
        echo dll file
        ) else (
            echo sys file
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set BINARIES=file1.dll fil2.dll fil3.sys

FOR %%G IN (%BINARIES%) DO echo %%G has a %%~xG extension.
```